# Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, packages, natbib, biber

I am writing an article in LaTex using the Solar Physics Journal template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/manuscript-template-for-solar-physics/mmbkwbkzbqwv. I have my bibliography in a file named References.bib. When I use the command `\usepackage[ backend=bibtex, style=numeric, ]{biblatex} \addbibresource{IOPEXPORT_BIB.bib}` in my preamble, my file does not execute, and I get this error `Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'natbib'.` If I do not include this command in my preamble, my citations show with a question mark sign. Kindly tell me what mistake I am doing here. Thank you.

```
\documentclass[namedreferences]
\usepackage[hyperref,optionalrh,showbiblabels]
% For Solar Physics 
%\usepackage[optionalrh]{spr-sola-addons} % For Solar Physics 
%\usepackage{epsfig}          % For eps figures, old commands
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{hyperref}% For eps figures, newer & more powerfull
%\usepackage{courier}         % Change the \texttt command to courier style
%\usepackage{amssymb}        % useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{color}           % For color text: \color command
\usepackage{breakurl}        % For breaking URLs easily trough lines
\def\UrlFont{\sf}            % define the fonts for the URLs
\usepackage{amssymb, amscd, amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,enumerate}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[
   backend=bibtex,
   style=numeric,
 ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IOPEXPORT_BIB.bib}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
% General definitions
% please place your own definitions here and don't use \def but
% \newcommand{}{} or 
% \renewcommand{}{} if it is already defined in LaTeX
\newcommand{\BibTeX}{\textsc{Bib}\TeX}
\newcommand{\etal}{{\it et al.}}
\begin{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{article}
\begin{opening}
abcdef
\end{opening}
\end{article}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first few lines of code look wrong: `\documentclass` and `\usepackage` both need a mandatory argument in curly braces after the options in square brackets. Please correct the code, so that we can actually try it. (The information which document class you use is crucial.)

Comment: If the class is not available on CTAN, please also link to where we can obtain a copy (ideally the copy you used).

Comment: What I can see now without having seen more is that many journal classes or templates load `natbib`, which would mean that such a template/class is simply not compatible with `biblatex`. This means you cannot load `biblatex` and need to use the method to generate citations and the bibliography enforced by the class/template. Check the documentation/examples to see what they recommend.

Comment: unrelated but don't load `epsfig` in any document written this century,  don't specify `graphicx` and `parskip` twice

Comment: @Celdor the error message shows the class has loaded natbib, so if testing with article load natbib as well (before biblatex)

Comment: @moewe Thank you so much. I have checked a file in the template and it shows how to add bibliography. The problem was what you explained in your third comment. I only had to add `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{References.bib}` at the end of my document to get citations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Noted. Thank you:) On a different note, what would be a good template for a beginner who is writing papers in the field of Physics?

Comment: in general just use `article`  class and _only and packages as you need them_ The preamble you show loads many packages, most of which you are almost certainly not using, which just slows down processing and can lead to hard to debug package conflict errors. If you are submitting to a journal, use whatever class the publisher specifies rather than `article`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. I removed my comment. On the time of writing it I thought I was a first cementer.

Comment: I strongly agree with David here. The only reason to use a template like the one you linked here is if you want to submit to a journal/publisher that asks you to use this template. If you are writing a paper and are still deciding where to publisher it is usually much, much better to just stick to classical `\documenctlass{article}` and loading only packages you need. Then it is often possible to change to required publisher templates with acceptable effort.

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidCarlisle and @moewe! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The companion package `spr-sola-addons` to your class `solarphysics` that is loaded in your template loads the citation management package `natbib` by default.

`natbib` is a BibTeX/`thebibliography`-based citation package. As such it is completely incompatible with `biblatex` and its way of doing things. A document cannot load `biblatex` and `natbib` at the same time.

There is an option to stop `spr-sola-addons` from loading `natbib`, which means you might be able to run `biblatex` with it, but that appears to be a bad idea, since the `template.tex` that is available under the link you gave suggests to create the bibliography using `natbib` as follows

```
\bibliographystyle{spr-mp-sola}
\bibliography{<bib file>}
```

Just get rid of

```
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  style=numeric,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IOPEXPORT_BIB.bib}
```

and `biblatex`-only commands like `\printbibliography` and use the classical BibTeX-based code.